# Правильная реализация обновления программы

Tags: c++

Задался таким вопросом, как реализация автообновления программы. Принцип таков: пользователь запускает программу, далее работает наша программа -- если версия данной программы, к примеру **1.0**, а уже есть **1.1**, то программа скачивает новую версию и перезапускает программу, в итоге программа свежая.

**Как думаю я:** На сервере лежит файл ***version.txt*** (я думаю, можно и XML, хотя будет сложнее обрабатывать). Наша программа при каждом её запуске проверяет версию. Читаем файл version.txt с помощью средств c++ (если это возможно, **НЕ скачивая файл**) и сравниваем его с текущей версией (обычная переменная). Если версии одинаковые, то продолжаем работу программы. Иначе -- а тут много вариантов, можем предлагать скачивать, можем заставить. Я выберу принудительную загрузку, т.е. обязательно, либо старая программа работать не будет. Скачиваем последнюю версию программы и перезапускаем её.

Предложите свои варианты. Возможно в моем алгоритме есть и недостатки. Скажите как лучше по вашему.

*P.S. Интересует только алгоритм, решение и средства предлагайте по желанию.*

Comment: На самом деле, обновление исполняемых файлов — это лишь начало проблем. Вы должны смигрировать и _конфигурационные файлы_ (настройки). Это раз. Затем, на windows есть такая штука, как [roaming profiles](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2005/06/30/434209.aspx), это означает, что не только новые версии должны корректно работать со старыми настройками, но и старые — с новыми! Welcome to compatibility hell.

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Думаю можно так: нужно создать простенькую программу загрузчик (Loader), основную программу запретить запускать непосредственно, только через загрузчик (решения могут быть разные, не суть). Загрузчик проверяет файл на сервере (кстати на сервере в отдельном каталоге можно держать пустой файл просто с именем равным версии, например, 1.0 или 1.0.1.1b - тогда не надо будет скачивать/читать файл), если имеется более свежая версия, загрузчик скачивает необходимые файлы с ресурса обновления и устанавливает, и только после этого запускает программу.

Answer (score 3):

Не претендую на правильность решения, просто расскажу, как это сделано у меня.
При запуске программы раз в 4 дня (чаще нет смысла, я не выпускаю новые версии так часто) в фоновом потоке запускается проверка обновления (пользователь может и вручную запустить).

На сервере лежат такие файлики.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<UpdateInfo Name="iu_core" DownloadUrl="http://dl.bintray.com/zenden/zenden-image-uploader/iu_core_1430852282.zip" TimeStamp="1430852282" Date="05.05.2015 20:58:02" UpdateUrl="http://zenden.ws/updates/update.php?package=%name%&amp;ver=%appver%" CoreUpdate="1" DisplayName="Image Uploader 1.3.2-alpha.4435" Hash="80bd20e78b4dcac317a399ff8a72c225">
  <Info>[f] Fixed uploading video files from Explorer's context menu custom items
</Info>
</UpdateInfo>
```

Программа обращается на сервер к специальному скрипту, сообщает свою версию, название компонента (у меня несколько компонентов, которые обновляются отдельно), и скрипт возвращает нужный xml. Идет сравнение по `TimeStamp` с локальной версией этого файла и программа показывает пользователю предложение обновиться с описанием изменений в новой версии.

Если пользователь соглашается, программа перезапускает сама себя с правами админа, и скачивает файл по указанному `DownloadUrl`. Проверяет md5 хэш zip архива и распаковывает архив во временную папку.
Внутри архива есть еще один xml файл, где указано, в какие папки нужно раскидывать файлы. Перед перезаписью exe и dll файлов они переименовываются в `*.old`. После чего программа запускает новую версию с особым ключом, чтобы можно было проделать еще какие нибудь действия (как правило, не требутся).

Некоторые компоненты (не содержащие exe файлы) обновляются втихаря без ведома пользователя.

При моем подходе есть недостатки, при деинсталляции инсталлятором (InnoSetup), новые файлы, установленные с помощью авто-обновления, не удаляются.

Хотя наверно для обновления exe правильнее было бы скачивать инсталлятор и устанавливать его по-тихому, но мне лень переделывать. Мне нравится, как сделано обновление у браузеров ( гугл хром и т.д.), программа обновляется сама, а пользователь даже не замечает. Но ради этого программа установлена в папку пользователя, а не в Program Files. Причем, если не ошибаюсь, у гугла **инкрементное** обновление, т.е. вместо огромного бинарника на 100 мб скачивается небольшой diff.

Но отказываться от встроенной системы обновления я не вижу смысла, моя программа (Image Uploader) должна часто обновлять поддержку хостингов, которые часто меняются, это жизненная необходимость. Обновление хостингов весит грубо говоря 50 кб, а сама программа 5 МБ.

P.S. Запрещать пользователям пользоваться старыми версиями программы - глупо. Я стараюсь поддерживать обратную совместимость со старыми версиями до разумного предела.

Answer (score 1):

В винде основная проблема состоит в том, что нельзя просто так взять и обновить файл, который запущен. Так что лучше всего сделать пускач, который будет обновляться не слишком часто. Он будет проверять версию основной программы и обновлять её ещё до запуска. Однако полностью это проблему не решит, поскольку иногда всё-таки нужно будет обновлять и сам пускач. В более старых версиях винды можно было хотя бы переименовывать папку, в которой находится запущенный файл, что чуть-чуть упрощало ситуацию. В современных версиях запрещено и это. Спасибо тебе, Билл, за то, что держишь нас в тонусе, не давая расслабиться!

В общем, в случае полного обновления, включающего пускач, придётся распаковывать архив с обновлением в соседнюю папку `<progname>.new`. Затем запускать из этой папки новый пускач со специальным ключом только для того, чтобы он, обнаружив себя в папке с расширением `.new`, переименовал старую папку `<progname>` в `<progname>.old` и запустил из неё старый пускач со специальным ключом. Тот в свою очередь должен переименовать папку с новой версией в `<progname>` и запустить из неё пускач уже без всяких ключей. И - вуаля! - обновлённая версия программы запущена и работает. Осталось лишь удалить старую версию в папке `<progname>.old`. Но это лучше делать не сразу, а, скажем, спустя неделю. Пускач должен просто проверять существование такой папки каждый раз. И удалять её, если та папка, из которой он сам запущен, существует уже как минимум неделю.

Несмотря на то, что такой процесс обновления выглядит сложно, реализовать его вполне реально. Глаза боятся, а руки делают. Я такое делал в молодости. Более того, моя реализация была ещё сложнее. Она проверяла у новой версии ЭЦП, а также умела обновлять настройки программы в реестре.

Comment: В этих манипуляциях просто нет смысла, просто скачиваем `msi` или `exe` установщик и запускаем его в тихом/полном режиме. Не нужно никаких ручных манипуляций с установкой проводить, это просто неправильно.

Comment: @ixSci Я знаю способ ещё проще. Сразу делаем программу идеальной и никогда её не обновляем.

Comment: это тут причём? Я ещё раз повторяю, руками *никто здравомыслящий* ничего не обновляет. Это делается через запуск `msi`/`exe`, в зависимости от используемого установщика. Обновления заключаются в том, чтобы скачать нужный установщик в нужное время и запустить его. Т.е. способ в Вашем ответе это какой-то привет из win98

Comment: @ixSci Во-первых, никто здравомыслящий не использует установщики. Они ломают старую версию в случае неудачного обновления. Во-вторых, вопрос не в том, как использовать обновление, реализованное другими, а в том, как его реализовать самому.

Comment: Вы несёте чушь. Просто откровенную чушь. Установщики использует весь софт, который написан не студентами на коленке.

Comment: @ixSci Хорошо, скажу иначе. Серьёзный софт, требующий непрерывных обновлений, использует свой собственный установщик.